# The proper way to write two variable equal to each other

Tags: objective-c

I have this code below and I am getting an error. `Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'CGPoint')` I don't know how to write this the proper way. And leads?

The error is on the if statement.

```
        CGPoint shadowpoint = CGPointMake(positionX, positionY);
        CGPoint objectPoint = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
        userObject.center = objectPoint;

        if (objectPoint == shadowpoint) {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing two `CGPoints`, the proper way to do this is to use the Function

```
CGPointEqualToPoint(point1, point2)
```

Comment: it worked for me! Thanks! :)